# Limitation of reduce in Ruby enumberable?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I am trying to solve problem 5 on Project Euler.  I am using the `.reduce(:+)` method and it seems to work for arrays up to 16 long.  Then when I try to pass it anything larger (20) for the answer it never calculates my end value.

```
require 'pp'
pp factors = (1..20).to_a
n = 1

result = []
loop do
  factors.each { |x| result << n % x }
  if result.reduce(:+) == 0
        break
  else
        result = []
  end
  n += 1
end
pp n
```

Comment: Maybe you tell us about problem 5 of project euler?

Comment: The question is "What is the smallest even positive number that is evenly divisible by all numbers from 1 to 20"?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can solve this with Integer#lcm.  Yep.  In one line too.

```
(1..20).to_a.reduce(:lcm)
```

Comment: It's helpful to suggest a better way, but only after you or someone else has answered the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I use 
    array.inject(:+) 
and never run into any issues with array length. Will be very helpful for the rest of Euler! It also works directly on ranges so you have no need to call .to_a:

(1..20).inject(:+) --> 210

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html

Answer (score 0):

For the question of the headline, is there a limitation for reduce?

No direct limitation, it is only limited by amount of computer-memory you need for the array. It will automatically use BigNum-class when normal integer overflows.

For example,

```
 (1..10000000).to_a.reduce(:+)
=> 50000005000000
50000005000000.class
=> Bignum
```

So there need to be another problem, or it is because the numbers and and so the runtimes are getting real big until your loop terminates.